# SQL: Finding a sum in an intersection with an interval

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following "actions" table:

```
"actions"."starts_at" (datetime)
"actions"."ends_at" (datetime)
```

I group the "actions" by hour for the last 24 hours like this:

```
 SELECT date_trunc('hour', actions.starts_at) AS "time"
 FROM actions
 WHERE (age(now(), actions.starts_at < '23:59:00'::interval)
 GROUP BY (date_trunc('hour', actions.starts_at));
```

I need to know, for each grouped hour, what is the sum of minutes in it that had an interaction with the period [start_at, ends_at].

Example:

```
Action 1:
  starts_at: 2020-05-11 09:40:00
  ends_at: 2020-05-11 10:13:00

Action 2:
  starts_at: 2020-05-11 09:53:00
  ends_at: 2020-05-11 10:04:00

Action 3:
  starts_at: 2020-05-11 11:03:00
  ends_at: 2020-05-11 11:04:00
```

What the output should look like :

```
. . .
2020-05-11 08:00:00 -> 0 (minutes)
2020-05-11 09:00:00 -> 27 minutes (20 minutes from action 1, 7 minutes from action 2)
2020-05-11 10:00:00 -> 17 minutes  (13 minutes from action 1, 4 minutes from action 2)
2020-05-11 11:00:00 -> 1 minutes (1 minute from action 3)
. . .
```

Comment: Do the actions ever overlap?  Can you provide a more comprehensive answer?

Comment: Yes we can have two actions that overlap like this:

first:
starts_at: 2020-05-11 09:40:00
ends-at: 2020-05-11 10:13:00

second:
starts_at: 2020-05-11 09:53:00
ends-at: 2020-05-11 10:03:00

Comment: How does the "group output" derive from just a single (start_at, ends_at) row that you have shown. Where does `08:00` come from if the smallest `start_at` value is `09:40`. Can you prepare a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12)  that sets up some sample rows in the table that should result in the desired output?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the db can have multiple actions, each with a different starts_at/ends_at combinaison. So the group by hour will sum the duration of intersection of all actions that have an intersection at the grouped hour.

Comment: I don't understand how the "grouped output" is created. Clearly not from the two example values (with 09:40 and 10:13). Where does the 08:00 hour come from in that output?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's an output example of the group by, I wrote the sql here : https://pastebin.com/BrLDWgsV, thank you

Comment: That still doesn't show the source data for that output. I also don't understand why you use a `group by` in that query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the output with title "Group:" in the question, is what the answer should look like. I'm so so sorry if you were confused. i corrected that in the question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If you're available for freelance hire, please contact me here https://pastebin.com/AAgYueJa

Comment: @Yassine, Perhaps you should clarify the question by adding multiple actions and show how they would be grouped by the hour. It is not clear (at least to me) what you are asking, even with the discussion in the comments

Comment: @HaleemurAli I added examples to actions, thank you.

Comment: @Yassine, shouldn't it be 7 minutes from action 2 for hour `09`?

Comment: @HaleemurAli yes you're right, corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each action generate the hours that it spans & for each hour construct a tsrange,

for each generated tsrange, sum the minutes in the intersection of the actions' tsranges with the generated tsranges.

A good way to build the intuition for when to reach for lateral joins is if in the plain english expression of your query, you are using the phrase `for each ... generate`

```
CREATE TABLE actions (start_at timestamp, end_at timestamp);
INSERT INTO actions VALUES 
  ('2020-05-11 09:40:00', '2020-05-11 10:13:00')
, ('2020-05-11 09:53:00', '2020-05-11 10:04:00')
, ('2020-05-11 11:03:00', '2020-05-11 11:04:00');

SELECT
  hours
, SUM(EXTRACT('minutes' FROM UPPER(tsint) - LOWER(tsint))) minutes
FROM actions a
JOIN LATERAL (
  SELECT
    hours
  , tsrange(a.start_at, a.end_at) * tsrange(hours, hours + interval '1 hour') tsint
  FROM GENERATE_SERIES(DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', a.start_at), DATE_TRUNC('HOUR', a.end_at), '1 hour') hours
) h ON TRUE
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
        hours        | minutes
---------------------+---------
 2020-05-11 09:00:00 |      27
 2020-05-11 10:00:00 |      17
 2020-05-11 11:00:00 |       1
(3 rows)
```

The hour `2020-05-11 08:00:00` is not represented in the query because it is not present in the source data.

Comment: what if we need to show the last 24 hours, and show 0 minutes if not data. thank you

Comment: Generate the last 24 house separately and join to this dataset, filling the null values with zero